# Django jQuery views user question

Tags: jquery, django-templates, django-views, jquery-tabs

I seem to be stuck and am not sure which is the best direction to take.

I have a few apps in my project and would like to combine three views into one template.

I have a userprofile in which I would like to display his **info, latest news feeds** and also his **photos**

Through this I am making use of **jQuery tabs**

I have defined my three tabs out of which one calls on a regular div and the other two are urls that get called in.

`<a href="wall/recent">wall</a>` and  `<a href="photos/recent">photos</a>`

the address bar reads the following when on a users profile
 `http://localhost:8000/profiles/profile_name/`

in my  `views.py` for `wall` and  `photos` looks like the following

```
@login_required
def index(request, template_name='wall/_index.html'):
    photos = Photos.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-id')
    context = { 'photos': photos, }

    return render_to_response(template_name, context,
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But if I then look at MY profile it is fine, but whenever I switch to another users profile it sill seems to display some of my information.

I know that request.user is looking at the logged in user, how do I obtain that user in the address bar and pass it on so it displays the correct info ie if `profile_name` = john then displays johns photos, recent wall items etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got a `urls.py` like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                      (r'^profiles/(?P<prof_name>[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)/$', 'appname.views.index'))
```

Then your view code can be modified like this:

```
@login_required
def index(request, prof_name, template_name='wall/_index.html'):
    photos = Photos.objects.filter(user__username=prof_name).order_by('-id')
    context = { 'photos': photos, }

    return render_to_response(template_name, context,
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

What this does is bind the name `prof_name` to whatever value is in the bit of the URL after `profiles/` and before the final `/`. Given the URL `/profiles/john/`, you'd end up with the `index` view being called, with `prof_name` set to `john`.

Comment: @ApPeL - great, thanks for accepting my answer - would you mind upvoting it too?